# Stop setKeepAliveTimeout handler from being called after application came foreground?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, appdelegate

For VOIP application we are sending PING packet to server every 10 minutes using setKeepAliveTimeout, everything works fine, however I'm not sure how to stop the handler from being called once application came foreground.

eg: Here is how I set the timeout

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{ [self backgroundHandler]; }];
```

Background handler:

```
- (void)backgroundHandler
{
    printf("10 minute time elapsed\n");
    // do some action...
}
```

Above function is being called even after application came foreground, I have read in Apple documentation to set the handler nil to stop it. I have tried like below in applicationWillEnterForeground

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:nil];
```

Still I'm getting call every 10 mins. How to handle this, Do I need to use flag only.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to invoke `clearKeepAliveTimeout` to stop the timer. `setKeepAliveTimeout:` is designed to keep a voip connection on and that's why it's periodically called.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it like this

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] clearKeepAliveTimeout];
}
```